# Webex XML APIs to schedule meeting on behalf on another user

Tags: webex

I have been working with the Cisco Webex XML APIs to perform all the CRUD operations on the single instance of meeting as well as the recurring meetings.

I wish to know, if there is a way using the current XML APIs to schedule a meeting on behalf on another user. I see on some Cisco communities where they mention about a property "schedulingPermission" within setUser that would let the user assign a delegate. But, I am unable to see/use that property.

Does anyone have an insight on how can I achieve this particular use-case?

Thanks

**EDIT**

There's a feature under the Meeting Schema referred to as "Role" which allows you to have an alternate host. So, User A can schedule meeting on behalf of User B, assigning User B alternate Host rights. But, the issue here is User B is using all the details of User A for the meeting, which is not what I am looking for.

Still looking for an answer where I can schedule the meeting and the meeting info will have all the details specific to User B and not User A.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://communities.cisco.com/docs/DOC-49935

> You would need to implement scheduling permissions.  Scheduling permission essentially allows an account (generally one with Site Admin privileges) to schedule meetings on behalf of another user. Before this can be done, the “master account” being used must be added to each host account’s scheduling permission.

With the XML API, this can be done with a request like:

```
<serv:message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service">
  <header>
    <securityContext>
      <webExID>jdoe</webExID>
      <password>letmein123</password>
      <partnerID>123abc</partnerID>
      <siteID>123456</siteID>
    </securityContext>
  </header>
  <body>
    <bodyContent xsi:type="java:com.webex.service.binding.user.SetUser">
      <webExId>bsmith</webExId>
      <schedulingPermission>jdoe</schedulingPermission>
    </bodyContent>
  </body>
</serv:message>
```

And then the meeting would be scheduled with:

```
<serv:message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service">
    <header>
        <securityContext>
            <webExID>jdoe</webExID>
            <password>letmein123</password>
            <partnerID>123abc</partnerID>
            <siteID>123456</siteID>
        </securityContext>
    </header>
    <body>
        <bodyContent xsi:type="java:com.webex.service.binding.training.CreateTrainingSession">
            <telephony>
                <telephonySupport>NONE</telephonySupport>
            </telephony>
            <accessControl>
                <sessionPassword>1q2w3e4r5t</sessionPassword>
            </accessControl>
            <schedule>
                <startDate>07/22/2013 00:00:00</startDate>
                <hostWebExID>bsmith</hostWebExID>
            </schedule>
            <metaData>
                <confName>Test</confName>
            </metaData>
        </bodyContent>
    </body>
</serv:message>
```

In general, for others operations, the admin account with the scheduling permissions would be used in the security context to authenticate the request and user account in the body.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had gone this route too, but the issue here is that, "jdoe" will be scheduling the meeting on behalf of everyone that requested to create a meeting on Webex (provided scheduling permissions is enabled). So, there definitely will be unique meetings but the teleconferencing information will be same (as for jdoe), which will result into one another jumping onto the same bridge which is for jdoe. So, there's no way "jdoe" can create a meeting with bsmith's information.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!